# GSON parse Array in array in array

Tags: android, json, parsing, exception, gson

I face this problem, from the API I'm getting an extens JSON with one object called coordinates, this object is an array that includes an array o array.

To be more clear look at this example:

```
"coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -0.087118,
                        51.508823
                    ]
```

Or in this pic you can see it better

[image: Or in this pic you can see it better]

So now I'm trying to parse it using GSON and I'm not being success. Can anyone give me an idea how to create the class for this?

Thank you

Comment: The text example is not consistent with the picture

Comment: why not? because of the numbers? in the pic I'm using Json editor chrome extension. Anyways it's solved now

Comment: From the text example it's not clear if it's `[[[x,y],[x,y]...]]` or `[[[x,y]],[[x,y]],...]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Coordinate extends ArrayList<Arraylist<Arraylist<float>>>{
}
```

Comment: Then say coordinate.get(0).get(0).get(0) etc

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example, where you wouldn't use Gson, but you'll get the idea.
Lets say that you put your JSON responce in a String called json

```
String json = ""coordinates": [[[-0.087118,51.508823]";

JSONArray firstArray = new JSONArray(json);
         for (int i =0; i < firstArray.length(); i++){

          JSONArray secondArray = firstArray.getJSONArray(i);
          for (int j =0; i < secondArray.length(); j++){

               JSONArray thirdArray = secondArray.JSONArray(j);
               for (int q =0; i < thirdArray.length(); q++){

                int x = thirdArray.getInteger("0");
                int y = thirdArray.getInteger("1");
               }
            }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the approach but there answer of @reactivemobile works